# Is there any way to use createMediaStreamSource on an AudioContext in Firefox 23?

Tags: html, firefox, audio, web-audio-api, getusermedia

Firefox 23 supports the Web Audio API in theory; however, the following snippet that works in Chrome Canary fails in Firefox Aurora:

```
var theAudioContext = new AudioContext;
navigator.getUserMedia({"audio": true}, function(stream) {
    var input = theAudioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    // theAudioContext.createMediaStreamSource is not a function
},
function(){ /* err */ });
```

Is support for this API planned as part of Firefox in the future, or is there an alternate way to work with MediaStreams today?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're working on support for MediaStreamAudioSourceNode, it will land in Nightly and Aurora soon.  Please follow this bug if you're interested: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=856361